# Normalizer.DECOMP is not anymore in java 7

Tags: upgrade, java-7, java-5

I have this in my code:
String name
StringnormString=Normalizer.normalize(name, Normalizer.DECOMP, 0);

this code is build in java 1.5 and I try to upgrade to java 1.7 but I cant find what the constant Normalizer.DECOMP means in java 1.7

Answer (score 1):

Try this Normalizer.normalize(name, java.text.Normalizer.Form.NFD);

Normalizer api changed slightly in java 6,so its usage is a bit different now.